# Cannot Get Array to Bind to PrimeNG Data Table

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, primeng, apollo

I am new to Typescript/Javascript/Angular 2 and I am having great trouble getting data to bind to PrimeNG's data table component.

This is complicated by trying to pass data between components. I have something like the following tree:

1. Student Details Component (Parent)
2. Search Component (When an ID is entered it filters up as output to the parent)
3. Student Service (takes the ID from the search and performs a GraphQL query that is passed back to the parent)
4. Student Requests Component (takes as input an array of request objects to bind to data table that is passed from the parent) - this is the component that doesn't seem to be working

The parent is coordinating all the components and services:

```
export class StudentDetailsComponent {
    requests: Array<RequestModel>;
    studentSearch: SearchModel;

    constructor(private toaster: ToasterService, private studentS: StudentService) { };

    searchStudent(event) {
        this.studentSearch = event;
        this.requests = this.studentS.getStudentRequests(this.studentSearch.studentId);
    }
}
```

Assume for the purposes of this example that the search component is working (it is providing an ID for the service to use, so I think it is fine).

The service then makes a GraphQL query using Apollo:

```
getStudentRequests(studentId: number): Array<RequestModel> {
        try {
            this.apollo.watchQuery<StudentRequestQueryResponse>({
                query: StudentRequestQ,
                variables: {
                    studentId: studentId
                }
            }).subscribe(({ data }) => {
                try {
                    this.loading = data.loading;
                    data.allApplicationRequests.nodes.forEach((element, index) => {
                        // console.log(data.allApplicationRequests.nodes);
                        this.requestPackages.push({
                            applicationRequestId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].applicationRequestPk,
                            studentId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].studentId,
                            visaTypeId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaVisaTypeByVisaTypeId.visaTypePk,
                            visaTypeName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaVisaTypeByVisaTypeId.visaTypeName,
                            applicationOriginCountryId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaCountryByCountryRequestLodgedId.countryPk,
                            applicationOriginCountry: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaCountryByCountryRequestLodgedId.countryName,
                            passportCountryId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].studentDetailByStudentId.metaCountryByPassportCountryId.countryPk,
                            passportCountry: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].studentDetailByStudentId.metaCountryByPassportCountryId.countryName,
                            healthInsuranceTypeId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaHealthInsuranceTypeByHealthInsuranceId.healthInsuranceTypePk,
                            healthInsuranceTypeName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaHealthInsuranceTypeByHealthInsuranceId.healthInsuranceType,
                            healthInsuranceProviderId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaHealthInsuranceTypeByHealthInsuranceId.metaHealthInsuranceProviderByHealthInsuranceProviderId.healthInsuranceProviderPk,
                            healthInsuranceProviderName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaHealthInsuranceTypeByHealthInsuranceId.metaHealthInsuranceProviderByHealthInsuranceProviderId.providerName,
                            universityCourseId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityCourseByUniversityCourseId.universityCoursePk,
                            universityCourseName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityCourseByUniversityCourseId.courseName,
                            universityFacultyId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityCourseByUniversityCourseId.metaUniversityFacultyByUniversityFacultyId.universityFacultyPk,
                            universityFacultyName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityCourseByUniversityCourseId.metaUniversityFacultyByUniversityFacultyId.facultyName,
                            universityPeriodId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityPeriodByUniversityPeriodId.universityPeriodPk,
                            universityPeriodCode: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityPeriodByUniversityPeriodId.metaUniversityPeriodCodeByUniversityPeriodCodeId.universityPeriodCode,
                            universityPeriodName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityPeriodByUniversityPeriodId.metaUniversityPeriodCodeByUniversityPeriodCodeId.universityPeriodName,
                            universityPeriodStartDate: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityPeriodByUniversityPeriodId.universityPeriodStartDate,
                            universityPeriodEndDate: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaUniversityPeriodByUniversityPeriodId.universityPeriodEndDate,
                            sourceBranchId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaSourceBranchOrganisationBySourceBranchId.sourceBranchOrganisationPk,
                            sourceBranchName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaSourceBranchOrganisationBySourceBranchId.sourceBranchName,
                            sourceCompanyId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaSourceBranchOrganisationBySourceBranchId.metaSourceCompanyOrganisationBySourceId.sourceOrganisationPk,
                            sourceCompanyName: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaSourceBranchOrganisationBySourceBranchId.metaSourceCompanyOrganisationBySourceId.sourceName,
                            requestOwner: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].requestOwner,
                            requestStatusId: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaRequestActionTypeByRequestActionId.requestActionPk,
                            requestStatus: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].metaRequestActionTypeByRequestActionId.requestStatus,
                            requestCloseTime: data.allApplicationRequests.nodes[index].requestClosedTime
                        });
                    });
                    // console.log(this.requestPackages);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    if (err instanceof TypeError) {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw new StandardErrorModel('info', '', 'We cannot find any records with those parameters.', err.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw new StandardErrorModel('error', '', 'We are having trouble connecting to the database.', err.message);
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new StandardErrorModel('error', '', 'We are having trouble connecting to the database.', err.message);
        }
        return this.requestPackages;
    }
```

Then I have this code in my Student Requests Component listening for changes to the `@Input()` to make sure it is working.

```
export class StudentRequestComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input()
    requests: Array<RequestModel>;

    ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
        console.log("INPUT");
        console.log(this.requests);
    }
}
```

I am then getting a nice array printed out with one object on the Chrome console:
[image: Screenshot Chrome Console]

But no data are appearing in my component which has the following HTML:

```
<div class="card card-w-title">
    <p-dataTable [value]="requests" [editable]="true" sortMode="multiple" expandableRows="false">
        <p-header>Requests</p-header>
        <p-column field="applicationOriginCountry" header="Application Origin Country" [editable]="false" sortable=true></p-column>
        <p-column field="passportCountry" header="Passport Country" [editable]="false" sortable=true></p-column>
        <p-column field="requestOwner" header="Request Owner" [editable]="true" sortable=true></p-column>
        <p-column field="requestStatus" header="Request Status" [editable]="true" sortable=true></p-column>
        <p-column field="requestCloseTime" header="Request Close Time" [editable]="false" sortable=true></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

Please help, as I am about to flip my lid with how annoying this problem is - I have tried a bunch of variations but I cannot get it to work.

EDIT:

Bizarrely, records appear in my component if I navigate to another route, come back, and search again i.e. more objects are added to the array. Once two objects are in the array, the data table seems to bind the first record (object 0 in the array).
[image][image]

Comment: where are you typing the `id` are you using any `textbox`?

Comment: Yes, the search component is a textbox and the ID is passed as `@Output()` from the search component to the parent then to the service.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: @Aravind I have tried to explain my issue in the question - it is not to do with the search component, it is to do with data being added to my student requests component, which contains a data table. I have added more detail to my question.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer? need to debug